# Place directly into folder without adding UUID folder

Tags: fine-uploader

I am sorry if this has been answered before but all my searching is not coming up with a result.

I would like to place files directly into the target path and it not generate the UUID folder and then place the file in there. I know about the whole same filename could exist that is why I change the filename on the onChange event before uploading

I have tried to modify the handler.php but either I am not editing the correct lines or something else is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long and tiring, trying to figure this out, hours I have found a work around on this.

If you sent a blank uuid to the script it will not create the folder and will just place the file in the folder that you told the endpoint to put items. Not sure if this is how the script is supposed to work but it works for me.

I do not have to worry about files that are named the same as i have the script also change the file name before it gets upload with pre-prending a unique string to the file name.

```
callbacks:
{
    onSubmit: function(id, name) {
        this.setUuid(id, "")
        console.log("onSubmit called")
    }
}
```